# stay on the same page after error validation in yii

Tags: php, yii

I would like to avoid redirecting after error validation.

I display a list of post and for each post the user can give a comment after clicking on a button.

This display the comment form under the choosen post.

If there is an error in validation of the comment I want to stay on the page and display errors beside the field in error (as default).

Here is **My controller action for the comment**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Comment;

        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];

            if($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);

            } else {

                 Yii::app()->end();

            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

**and the view**

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'comment-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comment'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'comment',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>140)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'comment'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

For the moment,  with Yii::app()->end();   it shows a blank page,  if I dont do nothing in the else part , then it continues and displays the create view (loosing some decoration)

**---Adding some more information**

Actually, what I have in my page is this

```
Post 1
(Comment form)
Commment  :   ........
Save

Post 2

Post 3
```

when I click on save without comment,  I want to stay in this page, giving the user the possibility to see where the error is  (comment is missing) and save it again.

Can you tell me where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Cthulhu   By removing Yii:app()->end  , the script continues show the create form,  so I loose the current page

Answer (score 0):

in the else block you have to tell yii to render the same page again. After calling $model->save() you get errors back in the model. So before Yii::app()->end(); call rendering of your page $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));

Comment: But in this case, it shows the create form loosing the list of post. Let me complete my post to better explain what I meant. @user3375273

Comment: What do you mean that you lose the list of post. In the controller you get the values for your $model ($model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];). And when you render the page again with $model as parameter then these values are included in the rendering of the page.

Comment: All you need is to set a placeholder for your attributes in your view.

Example: 

    <input type="text" name="input" value = <?= $model->someAttribute?>>